# Adding patients into my implemented linked list class

Tags: java, oop, collections, linked-list, nodes

I have written program where patients are added to a linked list. Right now i am able to get output. I tweaked my code so that **it inserts the patients according to the severity from highest to lowest and if the severity is the same then according to the time.** My patients class has three attributes name, arrival and severity.

**Edit 3**

I have added `compareSeverity` method in `Patient` class.

```
public boolean compareSeverity(Patient other) {
 boolean result = false;
 if(other.severity > severity) {
  result = true;
 } else if(other.severity == severity) {
    if(other.arrival > arrival) {
     result = true;
    } else {
      result = false;
   }
  } else {
     result = false;
  }
  return result;
 }
```

This is the `PatientNode` code snippet.

```
class PatientNode {
 public Patient data;
 public PatientNode next;

 public PatientNode(Patient data, PatientNode next) {
  this.data = data;
  this.next = next;
  }
}
```

This is the `add` method in `linked list` class.

```
public void add(String name, int severity) {
 lastArrival++;
 Patient patient = new Patient(name, lastArrival, severity);
 PatientNode current, previous;
 current = head;
 previous = null;
 if(head == null) {
  head = current = new PatientNode(patient, head);
  size++;
 } else {
   while(current!=null) {
    //previous = current;
    if(current.data.compareSeverity(patient)) {
     PatientNode n = new PatientNode(patient,current);
     size++;
     n.next = current;
     if(previous==null) {
      head = n;
     } else {
       previous.next = n;
     }
   
     return;
    }
   previous = current;
   current = current.next;
  }
 }
}
```

The output that i am getting right now is this however when the problem seems to be with the **same** `severity` patients.

I want my output to look like this:

> Patient 1, arrival 2, severity 3
>
> Patient 2, arrival 3, severity 3

Or if they have different severity then like this:

> Patient 1, arrival 2, severity 2
>
> Patient 2, arrival 1, severity 1

In short `severity` has to be in descending order and **if the severity is the same** then store them in ascending order according to `arrival`.

Any ideas/pointers or some pseudocode of how i can store patients according to severity  would be so great, thanks.

Comment: Are you required to implement this yourself? You really should be using a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Comment: yes i have to implement this myself. @4castle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your code-update with compareSeverity in it:

- The condition  `if(other.arrival > arrival) {` should be `if(other.arrival < arrival) {` and your `if`-clauses could be simplified in the `compareSeverity` method because you only need to specify when you need to set the value on `true` instead of `false` you initialized your variable with.

  ```
  public boolean compareSeverity(Patient other) {
      boolean result = false;
      if((other.severity > severity) || (other.severity == severity && other.arrival < arrival)) {
          result = true;
      }
      return result;
  }
  ```

  because it just sets a boolean value, you can even let it become:

  ```
  public boolean compareSeverity(Patient other) {
      return (other.severity > severity) || (other.severity == severity && other.arrival < arrival);
  }
  ```
- You had forgotten an if-condition in the `add` method after your while-loop. What to do if `current` had become `null`? This happens when you couldn't insert your patient in the linked list so you'll have to put it at the back as last element.

  ```
  public void add(String name, int severity) {
      lastArrival++;
      Patient patient = new Patient(name, lastArrival, severity);
      if(head == null) {
          head = new PatientNode(patient, head);
          size++;
      } else {
          PatientNode current, previous;
          current = head;
          previous = null;
          while(current!=null) {
              if(current.data.compareSeverity(patient)) {
                  PatientNode n = new PatientNode(patient,current);
                  size++;
                  //n.next = current; // overkill
                  if(previous==null) {
                      head = n;
                  } else {
                      previous.next = n;
                  }
                  return;
              }
              previous = current;
              current = current.next;
          }
          if(current == null){
              previous.next = new PatientNode(patient, null);
              size++;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I can provide you with [a working example](http://ideone.com/Vp6pCJ) of your updated code

Comment: Okay give me some time to copy this into my program. Hopefully i'll be bale to come up with some good news. It is some problem and i have been at it from yesterday.

Comment: Yeah everything is working fine now. I think i just forgot to put some lines. that's the problem by working continuously. Thank you so much. You have been so helpful. I liked how you simplified the `compareSeverity` method. Thanks again. :)

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your while-loop!

1. Be carreful when you change something in the LinkedList: be sure to change the right nodes. Suppose in your case the current list is

   ```
   node1 --> node2 --> node4 --> node5
   ```

   and we have a `PatientNode` `node3` that has to be inserted in the list just before `node4` like this:

   ```
   node1 --> node2 --> **node3** --> node4 --> node5
   ```

   The things we'll have to change are only the `next` field of `node2` that has to be `node3` and the `next` field of `node3` itself (has to be `node4`).
   If we look to your code, in the while-loop you have nodes `n` and `p`, respectively the new node that has to be added and the current node during the iteration. In the loop you verify if `n` has to come before `p` and when it has to, you do this:

   ```
   n.next = p.next;
   p.next = n;
   ```

   This is wrong! Compare it to the `node3` and the `node4` in the example: `n` has to come before `p` as `node3` had to come before `node4`. So `n` corresponds to `node3` and p corresponds to `node4`. **You have only to change the `next` field of the parent of `p`** (that corresponds to `node2`) **and of the `n` node. You don't need to touch `p`**. To solve this, you can simpely change the if statements in your while-loop: change `p.data` to `p.next.data`.
2. Another error you have in your loop is that you didn't put a break where you add a patient because it has a higher `arrival`. But I'll recommend you to use as less `break`s as possible. As you are setting the `added`-variable use its value in the loop-condition : `while(p.next!=null && !added){`
3. This is more an advice: use a proper `else if`-condition instead of using an `if` as only thing inside an `if` that is the only thing in the `else`-clause!
4. This is also an advice. I would strongely discommend a LinkedList where the last node retains a pointer to the first node (the `head`). Especially here because there is no code to update the `next` value of that last element if the `head` would change. This could generate quite strange results (as last element pointing to the second element instead of the first) and can lead to different errors if not enough attention is paid (espacially stackoverflow errors in case of recursion)

So finally your `add`-function should look like this:

```
public void add(String name, int severity) {
    Patient patient;

    lastArrival++;
    patient = new Patient(name, lastArrival, severity);
    PatientNode n = new PatientNode(patient, null);

    if(head==null) {
      head = n;
      size++;
      return;
    } else if(n.data.getSeverity() > head.data.getSeverity()) {
      n.next = head;
      size++;
      head = n;
      return;
    }

    PatientNode p = head;
    boolean added = false;
    while(p.next!=null && !added) {
      if(p.next.data.getSeverity() < severity) {
        n.next = p.next;
        p.next = n;
        added = true;
      } else if(p.next.data.getSeverity()== severity && p.next.data.getArrival() > lastArrival) {
        n.next = p.next;
        p.next = n;
        added = true;
      }
      p=p.next;
    }
    if(!added) {
      p.next = n;
    }
    size++;
}
```

I put back the `size++` in each case.

I copied your code with the corrections I proposed and produced [minimal working code](http://ideone.com/inC5sQ). I created the class LinkedPatients with minimal fields(`head`, `size`, `lastArrival` and only the `add` function) and the class `Patient` with the methods you posted and 3 fields(`name`, `arrival`, `severity`). I tried to recreate your three scenarios in the first output you posted (it seems you have a kind of `remove` method but you didn't post it so the last case is not perfectly the same). You can follow the link and check the output.